# Audio backend for 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, pulseaudio, alsa

Often the audio quality is very bad so I've to restart the audio backend.

When I'm using `ALSA` I can't since the command to restart it seems not to find the file (strange as ALSA works..) when I'm use pulseaudio, I can restart with `pulseaudio -k` in a terminal.

`OSS`  never worked to me. When Ubuntu used ESD, the audio always worked (Ubuntu 10.04 or maybe earlier).

Someone encountered similiar problem? Which backend do you use?

I've an integrated nvidia soundboard (MCP77/78 HDMI).

Comment: Please specify what it is that is 'bad' on your system

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has been using a very similar stack to the current one (PulseAudio on ALSA) by default since 8.04. If 10.04 worked for you, I'd take off the rose-tinted glasses because they're lying to you. Each sound system has its pros and cons. PulseAudio is just the best of a imperfect mix for most people.

The command to restart ALSA (on 11.04) is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/alsasound restart
```

You might need to install the `alsa-utils` package. That just does a load of things with `alsactl`.

As for poor sound quality, I find that sometimes funny balance/fade settings can cause major distortion. A tool like `padevchooser`'s mixer might help you straighten things out.

Comment: Now I'm on Pulseaudio (it uses ALSA?). I've already installed alsa-utils e alsactl... Now I'll try something with padevchooser and with pulse .conf file listed below (backupping the old one).

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/alsasound restart doesn't work... It says "command not found". However I'm trying to do some tricks with padevchooser (as recommended) and it seems to be a possible solution... We'll see :)

Answer (score 0):

To configure audio settings that affect sound quality we have a configuration file `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` where we can fine tune a lot of settings, depending on your indivdual system or problem. This file can be edited as root with any editor.

For my system the following settings turned out to be fine (leaving all other parameters commented out):

```
resample-method = speex-float-1
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
```

**Always make a backup of this file before editing in case you made changes that break your audio.**

Comment: It seems to happen random. I open an application, then another and after a while the audio is very disturbed... I'll try both the setting for alsa and pulseaudio :)

Comment: It often happens with nautilus or firefox opened (so when the CPU/ram is well stressed).

Comment: We still don't know what "it" is that is "disturbed". Try uncommenting `high-priority = yes` - this may slow down other applications.

Comment: It seems to be resolved with padevchooser and some ubuntu updates :)